# Not able to make click event in android data binding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

**View.Java**

```
package com.espresso.mvvmtestproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.espresso.mvvmtestproject.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;


public class View extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewContract.requiredMethods{


    ViewModel mModel;
    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Setting the layout
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mModel=new ViewModel(getContext());
        binding.setUser(mModel);
        binding.setHandlers(new MyHandlers());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return View.this;
    }


}
```

---

**ViewContract.java**

```
public interface ViewContract {
    interface requiredMethods{
        Context getContext();
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.espresso.mvvmtestproject.ViewModel"/>
        <variable
            name="handlers"
            type="com.espresso.mvvmtestproject.MyHandlers"/>
    </data>




    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="First Text"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Second Text"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Show Toast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::onShowToast}"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

---

**MyHandlers.java**

```
public class MyHandlers {

    public void onShowToast(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**ViewModel.java**

```
public class ViewModel {


    private Context mActivity;

    public ViewModel(Context context) {
        this.mActivity=context;
    }

    public void onShowToast(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

---

**ErrorLog**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
D:\Projects\Trp\MvvmTestProject\app\src\main\java\com\espresso\mvvmtestproject\View.java
Error:(8, 48) error: package com.espresso.mvvmtestproject.databinding does not exist
Error:(15, 5) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBinding
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match signature of any method handlers::onShowToast
file:D:\Projects\Trp\MvvmTestProject\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
loc:40:31 - 40:51
****\ data binding error ****
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.396 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: I made the project almost exactly as given and it worked fine. I believe that you didn't properly copy the `MyHandlers.onShowToast` because it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `MyHandlers` interface from class.

```
public class MyHandlers {
    public void onShowToast(View view);
}
```

Implement it in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, in your case it will be as follows

```
public class View extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewContract.requiredMethods, MyHandlers{

    ViewModel mModel;
    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Setting the layout
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mModel=new ViewModel(getContext());
        binding.setUser(mModel);
        binding.setHandlers(this);

    }        

    @Override
    public void onShowToast(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Override your interface method onShowToast and set the handler for your binding, and that's it, you are done with click events

Comment: @RaviRupareloya Rocking again in Data Binding

Comment: `activity_main.xml`, there is something missing ?

Answer (score 11):

In later versions of the DataBinding library you can just bind to your click event like this:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.save()}"
```

Then, in your viewmodel you can just add a listener like this:

```
public void save(){
 ...
 }
```